# php's mails not sended on gmail.com

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have this code

```
mail($to, 'Some Subject', 'message');
```

If `$to` is `gmail.com` mail server addres, mail is not sended, but If `$to` is some other mail server, for example `mail.ru`, message send successfully.

What may reason?

Comment: Answer: Gmail's spam filter

Comment: Are you sending from a real email address that Google's mail servers would be okay with? I'm guessing the answer is no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail blocks little servers because they tend to send most of the spam.

Edit: but I believe I made it work once, one second, I am searching the relevant code!

I did cut out a bit, but should still work.

```
public function send($sName, $sMail, $sSubject, $aTo, $sContent, $bHtml){
    $this->mailer = 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . \phpversion(). "\n";
    $this->ip = 'X-Sender-IP:' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";

    $this->from = 'From:' . $sName . '<' . $sMail . ">\n";
    $this->reply = 'Reply-To:' . $sMail . "\n";
    $this->contentType = "Content-Type: text/html\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

    $this->from .= $this->reply;
    $this->from .= $this->mailer;
    $this->from .= $this->ip;
    $aAttach = $this->checkAttachement();
    $this->from .= $this->contentType;

    foreach($aTo as $to){
        $to = \trim($to);
        if($to != "" && \strlen($to) > 5){
            mail($to, $sSubject, $sContent, $this->from);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Spam box.
Because services like this are used to send mass emails, GMail will usually block it.

Answer (score 0):

In your public domain DNS record for the domain your from email adress uses (like noreply@mydomain.ru), you need to create an SPF Record for your sending server/ip.

An SPF record might look like this:

```
v=spf1 include:my-php-server.ru ~all
```

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework